# Workflow assign user to handle node in given state

Tags: 7, users, workflows

I am using `Workflow` module to implement moderation policy in one of my project. It is working fine. 
But I want is when a user changes workflow state of user, he must be able to select a given user also from given user group, who will be responsible to manage the node in that state.

So, ideally it would be drop-down of user, form where admin can select user to whom the the node be assigned.

I searched a lot, but didn't find any solution yet. Is there any way to achieve this.

-- Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I am developing a module that address that very issue and some other things. Besides it is on sandbox yet, it is fully usable (I am using it on production).

> Workflow Hide Fields is an addon to the Workflow module.

You can clone it:

```
git clone --branch 7.x-1.x git://git.drupal.org/sandbox/fpap/2575131.git
```

And can visit the [module page](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/fpap/2575131).